# tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

This is my code:

```
list_users = ["1259850119245152257", "7173232",
          "1049586465477410816", "1337308835468386304", 
          "35801029", "60372896", "2411460916", 
          "191995162", "109498457", "1052635014616166400", 
          "1395018064396124160", "2553929341", "240133655",
          "1391184583698391046"]
giveawaystream.filter(follow=list_users)
```

and the error I get is:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]
```

No idea why, any help

Comment: I assume that one of the users is no longer active / deleted. Have you checked each of the user IDs in turn?

Comment: yes i have and i just double checked.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, and I don't think streams error in this way. What's the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Users\Johan\Documents\Code\code\python\projects\twitter\shittergiveawaybot\target.py", line 64, in <module>
    giveawaystream.filter(follow=list_users)
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 474, in filter
    self._start(is_async)
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-

Comment: packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 389, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 320, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 289, in _run
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]

Comment: self._read_loop(resp)
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 351, in _read_loop
    self._data(next_status_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 323, in _data
    if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 54, in on_data

Comment: if self.on_status(status) is False:
  File "d:\Users\Johan\Documents\Code\code\python\projects\twitter\shittergiveawaybot\target.py", line 52, in on_status
    user = api.get_user(tag)
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 253, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)

Comment: You should edit your question to include this traceback rather than splitting it up without formatting in multiple comments. In the future, you should also provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code if you're not providing all of the relevant code, as well as the full traceback with any questions regarding issues you're encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the traceback, this is occurring in your code on line 52 of `target.py` within `on_status`, where `user = api.get_user(tag)` errors, presumably because `tag` does not refer to a user that Twitter's API can find.